# How can I use a variable outside of the .then() scope

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following situation:

Why does the clients variable resolve in undefined when I call it below;

```
function getClientList() {
  TeamSpeak.connect({
    host: "localhost",
    serverport: 9987,
    nickname: "NodeJS Query Framework",
  }).then(async (teamspeak) => {
    const clients = await teamspeak.clientList({ clientType: 0 });

    if (clients) return clients;
    else return null;
  });
}
```

When I call it like that it resolves as undefined

```
const clients = getClientList();
```

Comment: You don't return the promise chain (or anything else) from the function.

Comment: It still resolves as undefined if I don't return anything

Comment: You're already not returning anything, that's why it's undefined.

Comment: Ok so how could it be done?

Comment: ..._do_ return the promise chain from the function?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is that you cannot use a resulting variable until the Promise resolves. Whether you use `.then` or `await` it's really the same mechanism and you can't access the result of your call until it's ready.

You can only get the results of it by waiting for the `Promise` to resolve. This can be done by using `await` if your function is marked as `async`, or by using the `.then()` function on the `Promise` since it will get called after the result is ready.

Think of the `Promise` as a black box that has a `then` function in it. Remember that each `.then()` function also returns as a `Promise` object which is why you can chain them as `promise.then(...).then(...).then(...);`. Your code then looks like this:

```js
function getClientList() {
  PROMISE1.then(someFunction);
}
const clients = getClientList();
```

Note that even though it spans multiple lines, your `getClientList` function is really just one line of code `TeamSpeak.connect(...).then(...);`

There are a few things wrong with your code. Let's go through them one by one:

1. The `getClientList` function doesn't return anything explicitly. In its most basic form it's `function getClientList() { someCall(); }` and that returns `undefined` by default.  That's why `clients` is always `undefined`.
2. If you add a return statement to the function, it will return a `Promise` and might look like this:

```js
function getClientList() {
  return PROMISE1.then(someFunction);
}
const clients = getClientList();
```

This is better because `clients` is not `undefined` any more, but it will be the `Promise` that may not have finished its work yet. To see the result of the call you'd need to use the `then` function like `clients.then(result => console.log(result))` to allow it to wait for the asynchronous work to complete.

3. You're using both `.then` and `async`/`await`. It will probably be cleaner and easier to work with if you go with one or the other (`await` is my preference). Your code can look like this:

```js
async function getClientList() {
  const teamspeak = await TeamSpeak.connect({
    host: "localhost",
    serverport: 9987,
    nickname: "NodeJS Query Framework",
  });
  const clients = await teamspeak.clientList({ clientType: 0 });
  return clients || null;  // returns as a Promise resolving to clients or null
}
const clients = await getClientList(); // assuming you're in another async fn
```

4. There is no error handling. If any of the asynchronous calls fail then the `Promise` will either reject or cause an exception. You should handle that by either surrounding it with a `try`/`catch` block at some level, or by adding `.catch()` after the final `then`, or by adding a second function to the `.then()` call to handle a rejection.

So putting it all together your code could look like this:

```js
async function getClientList() {
  const teamspeak = await TeamSpeak.connect({
    host: "localhost",
    serverport: 9987,
    nickname: "NodeJS Query Framework",
  });
  return await teamspeak.clientList({ clientType: 0 }) || null;
}

// Example calling getClientList using ".then"
getClientList()
  .then(
    client => {
      /* use the client value in this scope */
    }, 
    reason => {/* report the reason for rejection */}
  )  // end of .then
  .catch(err => {/* report the error */});

// Example calling getClientList using "await"
try {
  const client = await getClientList();
  /* use the client value in this scope */
} catch (err) {/* report the error */}
```

No matter how you make the call, you're only able to access the `clients` value (returned by calling the `clientList` function) within the scope of either the `.then` or after `await`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call getClientList() the inner "connect" function is started instantly in your library while the "then" callback is left to be executed in a future you can't know (when your library has completed the task triggered in "connect").

Preparing this "then" callback is done instantly, so getClientList() ends without returning anything.

The "return" instructions inside "then" are not returns for getClientList() but for the one who executes the callback (the code in your library).

**What you can do is promissify the process**: Return a promise that can be waited for and will be solved in the future when callback has been executed.

Try it like this:

```
function getClientList() {
  // Tell the function caller that he will have the result at some time in the future.
  // In other words: return a promise.
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => { 
    TeamSpeak.connect({
      host: "localhost",
      serverport: 9987,
      nickname: "NodeJS Query Framework",
    }).then(async (teamspeak) => {
      const clients = await teamspeak.clientList({ clientType: 0 });
      // Give the caller that is waiting by holding the promise the desired result.
      if (clients) resolve(clients); 
      // Throw error to the caller that is waiting by holding the promise .
      else reject('Connect failed');
    });
  });
}
```

But notice you must await for the promise inside an "async" function. Otherwise you would block the main thread.

```
async function main() {
  const clients = await getClientList();
}
```

Do set a try/catch as the promise might throw an error if "reject" is executed:

```
async function main() {
  try{
    const clients = await getClientList();
  } catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    // Will show:
    // Connect failed
  }  
}
```